# Add own C++ class into existing MFC app

Tags: c++, class, mfc, include

This is a follow-up to a question I asked before, but the answers provided lead to new problems. I have my own Grid class which looks like this:

```
class Grid{

public:

    Grid(HWND wnd);

    void paint(CDC &dc, int sqr, bool axis);        //paint the grid
    void tag(CDC &dc);

private:
    int square;                                     //square size
    CRect frame;                                    //client area size

};
```

and

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Grid.h"


Grid::Grid(HWND wnd)
    {
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(wnd, &rect);                  // get client area size
    frame.left = rect.right / 2 - 387;          // fit frame to margin
    frame.right = frame.left + 774;
    frame.top = rect.bottom - 874;
    frame.bottom = rect.bottom - 100;
}
[...]
```

Now I wanted to include these in CMainFrame class given by the MFC app wizard, which is why I added following to MainFrm.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "ChildView.h"
#include "Grid.h"

class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
    [...]

    Grid myGrid(HWND wnd = NULL);

    [...]
}
```

and then added in MainFrm.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GridTargets.h"
#include "MainFrm.h"
#include "Grid.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// CMainFrame construction/destruction

Grid myGrid;

CMainFrame::CMainFrame() : myGrid(GetSafeHwnd())
{}

CMainFrame::~CMainFrame()
{
}

[...]
```

but the compiler gives a couple of errors regarding MainFrame.cpp, which are:

```
Error   3   error C2600: 'CMainFrame::CMainFrame' : cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)    c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\mainfrm.cpp 31  1   GridTargets
Error   4   error C2436: 'myGrid' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\mainfrm.cpp 32  1   GridTargets
Error   5   error C2228: left of '.paint' must have class/struct/union  c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\mainfrm.cpp 142 1   GridTargets
Error   2   error C2079: 'myGrid' uses undefined class 'Grid'   c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\mainfrm.cpp 29  1   GridTargets
Error   1   error C2011: 'Grid' : 'class' type redefinition c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\grid.h  1   1   GridTargets
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Regards,
Michen

Comment: `myGrid` is declared as a member function (rather than a data member). Did you mean to declare it this way? If so, then the `: myGrid(...)` part in `CMainFrame` constructor makes no sense. If you do want a data member of type `Grid`, then that would be `Grid myGrid;`

Answer (score 1):

I have to guess a bit, without the rest of the code, but at least some of the errors should be clear:

> Error   3   error C2600: 'CMainFrame::CMainFrame' : cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)    c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\mainfrm.cpp 31  1   GridTargets

This is because you do not declare the constructor in "CMainFrame". C++ inserts a constructor for you, but also an implementation.

> Error   4   error C2436: 'myGrid' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\mainfrm.cpp 32  1   GridTargets

I am not sure ... but I believe this is also because you do not define the constructor and it can not initialize a member Variable.

> Error   5   error C2228: left of '.paint' must have class/struct/union  c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\mainfrm.cpp 142 1   GridTargets

I would have to see the corresponding code.

> Error   2   error C2079: 'myGrid' uses undefined class 'Grid'   c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\mainfrm.cpp 29  1   GridTargets

You probably forgot to include "Grid.h"?

> Error   1   error C2011: 'Grid' : 'class' type redefinition c:\users\michen\documents\repos\gridtargets\gridtargets\grid.h  1   1   GridTargets

This looks like you are missing code Guards. Place:

```
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H
[...]
#endif
```

In you Grid.h file.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. You need to set the constructor default in the grid header file. That is where you put HWND = null. In the grid constructor definition.

So, your header:

```
#pragma once
class Grid
{
public:
    // A default constructor must provide a default value for all of it's parameters (if it has any)
    Grid(HWND hWhatever = NULL);
    ~Grid();
private:
    HWND m_hWhatever;
};
```

Your source:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Grid.h"


Grid::Grid(HWND hWhatever /*NULL*/)
    : m_hWhatever(hWhatever)
{
}


Grid::~Grid()
{
}
```

That is the right approach to setting the class up.

Comment: OK, after much confusion I found the problem: For one I was missing these so called 'code guards' Nathan mentioned. On the other hand I never wanted a default constructor Grid(); in my grid header files. That's because I thought it would be best to pass the GetSafeHwnd result to the constructor for Grid member variable initialization. But somehow Grid myGrid; always needs a default constructor, which when provided is naturally without parameters. Putting Grid myGrid(GetSafeHwnd()) always failed, as well as calling it in the member initialization of CMainFrame. Solution: Write myGrid.init(HWND)

Comment: I have just provided an example. I am not saying you do need a parameter or not in your case. I am just conveying the right way to set up your constructor.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Your response was very appreciated.

Comment: @Michen, you are welcome. :) Would you mind marking it as useful by clicking the up arrow please?